# How to set form background image

Tags: codenameone

How can I set a form background with an image. 
I tried using the image Viewer component, but the image doesn't span the entire screen.

Comment: Ask clearly,what do you want ??

Answer (score 3):

You can add a backgroudn image with the CodenameOne Designer. In your theme , you can edit the "Form" uiid and set background as **IMAGE** 
Like this : [image]

Comment: Thanks. Am gonna try this

Comment: FYI I would recommend using scale to fill or fit rather than scale in this situation. Just looks better.

Comment: Does this applies to all forms or just a single form

Comment: I tried Tim said, but this works for all forms. I just want to set for a single form

Comment: You can set the UIID of the form using `myForm.setUIID("WithBackground")` then customize the "WithBackground" UIID. Or you can use `myForm.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(...)` & `setBackgroundType` see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html & https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html